# Register custom URI scheme for href in epub XHTML

Tags: xhtml, uri, url-scheme, epub

I'm developing an epub file and checking it with `epubcheck`. I'm getting this warning:

```
Non-registered URI scheme type found in href.
```

Epub files contain XHTML content documents which can have `<a>` tags pointing out to remote resources. In this case, the `href` attribute contains a URI whose protocol is `bitcoin:`.

**Question**: How can I register the `bitcoin:` protocol scheme for `href` attributes in my epub's XHTML so that `epubcheck` no longer reports a warning?

Answer (score 0):

EPUB viewers do not understand the `bitcoin` scheme, since they do not include the logic to participate in a blockchain.

Nothing you declare in your EPUB file is going to provide that capability to the viewer. If it were possible to do so, that would effectively become a remote code execution vulnerability.

Your EPUB file should instead link to a resource that can handle the `bitcoin` scheme, such as a web app that can perform blockchain operations.